# What can be used to import and export metadata in version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

What can be used to import and export metadata in version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB?
How to import and export the metadata of Apache IoTDB Version 1.3? I have searched all over the official documents and FAQs, but there is no information on this topic. In the official documents of 0.13 version, however, there is a tool to export metadata, but the metadata settings seem to have changed, so I don't know if this tool can still be used. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

For version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB, there is no separate metadata export or import function, since the metadata will be automatically created when you import data. The data type can be specified in the frontend or inferred in the backend. You can check the type inference and necessary command examples in the official user guide.